# Vertex Shader Particle Movement

Tags: math, opengl-es, vector-graphics, vertex-shader

I want to move my particles by a few given attributes. The particles should slow down to a stop as they reach the end of their lifetime

```
result = a_pos + a_direction * lifetime * mix(a_speed, a_speed_end, normalized_lifetime);
result.w = 1.0;
gl_Position = u_projection * u_model_view * result;
```

This doesn't work as I'd hoped it would because it doesn't consider previous movements, so when normalized_lifetime reaches 1, the particle is basically set to a_pos again since a_speed_end is 0. How do I go about this?

EDIT: More information:

a_pos = startposition

a_direction = normalized direction vector

lifetime = current lifetime of the particle

a_speed, a_speed_end = desired start/end speed

They should move on a straight line along the direction vector, no CPU updates

Comment: How do your particles move? On a straight line? Randomly? Are there CPU updates involved?

Comment: What OpenGL version are you targeting?

Answer (score 2):

you want a equation like `-a_deceleration*t^2+a_initial*t+a_pos`

a bit of physics:

initial speed is `a_speed`
`a_speed_end` is `a_speed - a_deceleration*total_life` so `-a_deceleration = (a_speed_end-a_speed)/total_life`

so your equation becomes

```
result = a_pos + a_direction * lifetime * a_speed 
               + a_direction * normalized_lifetime * normalized_lifetime * (a_speed_end-a_speed);
```

edit: looking at the formulas in wikipedia there is an easier one

```
result = a_pos + a_direction * lifetime * (a_speed + mix(a_speed, a_speed_end, normalized_lifetime))/2
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.... They seem to slow down a bit but certainly don't stop at the end of its lifetime. I've included more detailed information on the variables above! Thanks for the help anyways, I don't know much about physics, what's the formula above called?

Comment: it's displacement with constant acceleration [see the wiki for the exact forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration)

Comment: I think the formula is right but the numbers are wrong. What I want is for example for the particle to travel for 5 seconds at decelerating speed and when reaching those 5 seconds it should come to a stop, so I'd need to calculate the appropriate acceleration first I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for ratchet freak for pointing me to the right direction, helped a lot! The final solution was to calculate the acceleration first

```
a_acceleration = (endspeed - startspeed) / total_lifetime;
```

The final formula is then:

```
pos = a_pos + ((0.5 * a_acceleration * current_lifetime * current_lifetime) + (a_start_speed * current_lifetime)) * a_direction;
pos.w = 1.0;
gl_Position = u_projection * u_model_view * pos;
```

For example, with a startspeed of 5, endspeed of 0 and lifetime of 5 the particle will slowly decelerate and come to a total stop after 5 seconds.